# Retrieve only one parameter value from aws ssm get-parameter command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

How can I print only the value of Value attribute from the below output of the following command

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name "/test/ip/cidr" --profile test
{
    "Parameter": {
        "Name": "/test/ip/cidr",
        "Type": "String",
        "Value": "172.18.0.0/20",
        "Version": 1,
        "LastModifiedDate": 1585251360.78,
        "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:123233:parameter/test/ip/cidr",
        "DataType": "text"
    }
}
```

Tried running the below command but prints  like [{"Value": "172.18.0.0/20"}] but just want to see only 172.18.0.0/20

```
aws ssm get-parameters --names "/test/ip/cidr" --query "Parameters[*].{Value:Value}" --profile test
[
    {
        "Value": "172.18.0.0/20"
    }
]
```

Comment: I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet only one answer was ever accepted. If all other answers were not helpful, then at least a comment why they fail to address the issue is a good practice. Accepting good answers not only reduces duplicates but it also makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will do that.

Comment: @SRE when? It is now two years later.

Answer (score 22):

You can add `--output text` and modify your `--query`:

```
aws ssm get-parameter --name "/test/ip/cidr" --profile test \
  --query "Parameter.Value" --output text
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you